# Is it mandatory to write ready function every time while doing jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Is it mandatory to write `$(document).ready(function () {... })` every time ?
Can't we do it without this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for placing your code inside this function is that it will get called once the DOM has loaded - meaning that all the elements are accessible. Calling jQuery selectors without this function means that the elements have not necessarily been loaded into the DOM and might not be accessible (and you'll see weird results or nothing at all from your code).

So in essense, yes, it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` makes sure your code runs when the document is ready (i.e. fully loaded). If you don't need to interact with the document, you don't need this. If you put your Javascript at the end of the document, you probably don't need it either. You *should* put your code into a `function () { }` though to namespace it either way.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready means the code inside this box will be executed once the all document is ready (loaded). It is considered as safe programming but not mandatory.

For example you call a function in script tag do_something(); and this function is in a js file which is not loaded yet then you will get javascript error.

If you put function like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    do_something();
});
```

you are making sure that when function get called all js files will be there to server.

Comment: Ok.But sometimes am not getting output without this line

Comment: because you might be getting javascript error in you function call

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use that line, and just include the javascript in your body, it will execute as soon as it's loaded. If it's trying to act on DOM elements that have not yet loaded, unpredictable results will occur.... better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's ready() function is run after the page's content is loaded.  This is relatively equivalent to using `<body onload="function1();function2();">`

If you want to call multiple functions when the page is done loading, you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function1();
  function2();
});
```

In order to use javascript, you must call it somewhere.  This can be in body "onload", jQuery's ready() function, or an event, like a mouse click event.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't always have to do this. You only use it if you want to make sure whatever is inside the ready function loads before the page is displayed in the browser. If you do not care to load the script before page load, then you can just put the script at the end of the page before the closing body tag.

Also As a shortcut to `$(document).ready(function ()` you can do `$(function()`